Which sense of "establish" is used in
This is a Merriam Webster's definition for the verb "install".

to establish in an indicated place, condition, or status
installing herself in front of the fireplace

I know that "establish" can mean:
Establish (verb):
b : to put (someone or something) in a position, role, etc., that will last for a long time
As a young doctor he worked hard to establish himself in the community.
They want to establish their children in the family business.(Britannica Dictionary)
Does this mean that the person who's "installing herself in front of the fireplace" will spend a prolonged period of time in front of that fireplace? Is the long time period required or install yourself somewhere can simply mean going there for a while? Is the definition of "establish" from Britannica the right one for this context?

You did not get the right definition for "establish oneself [as x]".

That's probably the best definition, but "long time" is a vague term that depends on the context. In this case, she expects to sit in front of the fire for a while, perhaps to read a book for an hour or more.
Contrast this with sitting by the fire just long enough to warm yourself after coming in from the cold.

It is a humorous exaggeration  to say that someone "installed herself in front of the fire".  She has claimed that spot and intends to remain there for some time.
Consider:

Puppet governments were installed in the countries the empire had conquered.


establish oneself as x
Cambridge Dictionary
to cause yourself to be accepted as being something:

spent several years trying to establish myself as a painter.
The pair have established themselves as a dominant force in the sport.

The OP's examples work fine:

As a young doctor he worked hard to establish himself in the community.     * They want to establish their children in the family business.


But, "to cause yourself to be accepted as being something" does not fit the context of "establishing yourself in front of a fireplace". I noticed that my definition I provided originally also don't fit. I though "position" meant "physical position" when I was posting it.

@StaticBounce install is temporary, establish is not really temporary.
